# Do flock locks reset after a system restart?

Tags: flock

Let's say the system powers down unexpectedly due to a power outage.

Are flock locks always considered to be "unlocked" when the system starts up?

<s>On Linux, flock relies on fcntl(...) (file descriptors).</s>

Asked another way: Is it unnecessary to manually call `flock -u <lock_filename>` when the system first starts up? (i.e. from cron @reboot)?

**Update**:

BSD flock man pages says:

```
Locks are on files, not file descriptors.   That is, file descriptors
duplicated  through dup(2) or fork(2) do not result in multiple instances
of  a lock, but rather multiple references to a single lock.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Linux guru friend here mentions that there is a kernel locks table (for file locks) (usually stored in memory) which disappears on a reboot.

And that the file lock is just there for as long as the process is running.

Answer (score -1):

According to the linux man page:

> Locks created by flock() are associated with an open file table entry.

[This is a data structure in the kernels memory](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~franco/OpSys-304-427/lecture-notes/node27.html) and not in the file system that may be on persistent disk storage.

Open files are closed when the process exits - thus flocks are valid only as long as a  process holding it is running.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The FreeBSD System Calls Manual's [flock](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=flock&sektion=2)(2) explicitly says: "Locks are on files, not file descriptors."

Comment: I've replaces `file descriptor` with `open file table entry`. By files, the man page does NOT mean physical files on the disc though.